# sizeof applied to the name of an array vs a pointer to the first element of the array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, sizeof

Suppose I declare `int v[]={1,2,3,4,5};`

I have been taught that `v` is a pointer to the first element in the `v` array. When I call apply `sizeof` to `v`, it returns 20, which I know is `5*sizeof(int)`, because there are 5 elements in the array.

`v+0` is also a pointer to the first element in the array, but `sizeof(v+0)` is 4.

Why is `sizeof(v)`=20 and `sizeof(v+0)`=4?

I would expect that `sizeof(v)` also returned 4, as `v` is a pointer, but instead it somehow also contains the information regarding the number of elements stored in the array. What is the explanation for this?

Comment: *"I have been taught that v is a pointer"* - You were taught wrong. Shame on your teachers.

Comment: `v` is an array, not a pointer.  The thing about arrays is that they decay to pointers, but they are not exactly pointers.  `v+0` decays the `v` to a pointer to do pointer arithmetic, and as that expression is a pointer rather than an array, the `sizeof` operator treats it as such.

Comment: I've seen it said that the first step to understanding C is to know that arrays are pointers. The second step to understanding C is to know that arrays are not pointers.

Comment: I suggest you read section 6 of the [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/).

Comment: @StoryTeller
I was partially wrong. I've just checked my lecture and it says "the name of an array is a constant pointer to the first element in it"

Comment: @ChristianGibbons
Thank you. Pointer decaying was not mentioned in our lectures but I'll look more into it.

Comment: @Andrei - The name of the array is not a pointer at all.

Comment: No offense, the most technically correct comment here is by @pmg. I don't understand why it's not upvoted.

Comment: @Andrei: While it's not a good *learning* resource (it has no tutorial information in it), you might want to bookmark the [online version](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) of the C language standard.  It's not easy reading, but you might want to compare your notes against it as you go through your class.  C is often taught poorly by people who were themselves taught poorly, and a lot of misinformation and bad practice have been passed down.  The standard is the primary reference - if your notes disagree, go with what the standard says.

Comment: @JohnBode All right, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have been taught that `v` is a pointer to the first element in the `v` array.

You have been taught incorrectly.  `v` is not a pointer - no space for a pointer is materialized as part of the array.  What you get is something like this:

```
   +---+
v: | 1 | v[0]
   +---+
   | 2 | v[1]
   +---+
   | 3 | v[2]
   +---+
   | 4 | v[3]
   +---+
   | 5 | v[4]
   +---+
```

and ***not*** this:

```
   +---+
v: |   |
   +---+
     |
     |
     V
   +---+
   | 1 | v[0]
   +---+
   | 2 | v[1]
   +---+
   | 3 | v[2]
   +---+
   | 4 | v[3]
   +---+
   | 5 | v[4]
   +---+
```

Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, or is a string literal used to initialize a character array in a declaration, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`", and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

When you write something like `foo( v )`, or `printf( "%p\n", (void *) v)`, or even just `v[i]`, the *expression* `v` is converted from type "5-element array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`", and the value of the expression is the same as `&v[0]`.

However, when you write `sizeof v`, that conversion doesn't happen - `sizeof` evaluates to the number of bytes in the entire array (5 * `sizeof (int)`).  Similarly, the type of the expression `&v` is `int (*)[5]` (pointer to 5-element array of `int`), not `int **`.

This is why `sizeof v` yields 20, while `sizeof (v + 0)` yields 4 - in the second case, `v` is *not* the operand of `sizeof`, the *expression* `(v + 0)` is the operand of `sizeof`.  In the expression `(v + 0)`, `v` decays to type `int *`.  Note that you will get a different result if you write `sizeof v + 0` - `sizeof` has higher precedence than the addition operator `+`, so that expression would be parsed as `(sizeof v) + 0`.

Comment: "operand of the sizeof or unary & operators ..." --> Also  the `_Alignof` operator.

Comment: @chux: I thought that was an error in the online draft, and was struck from the final, published version (which I don't have).  Is that not correct?

Comment: IDK, I will review.  It makes sense to me that `complex long double x[42]; ... _Alignof x` should be aligned per `complex long double` and not per the pointer to such.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof v` = `20` because there are `5` elements each of size `4` byte in your system. Upto this everything is right. But then you mentioned `v` is a pointer. Is it so?

Nope. Array is different from a pointer. Why there is confusion?

In context of `sizeof(v+0)` this will explain a bit:

There are two things that you may find helpful from standard (Under pointer arithmetic) `§6.5.6.2`

> For addition, either both operands shall have arithmetic type, or one
>   operand shall be a pointer to a complete object type and the other
>   shall have integer type. (Incrementing is equivalent to adding 1.)

And also from `§6.5.6.7`

> For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to an object that is
>   not an element of an array behaves the same as a pointer to the first
>   element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its
>   element type.

So here `v` decays into pointers as an operand to `+` not an operand to the `sizeof` operator. In fact array *doesn't* decay into pointer when used as an operand of `sizeof` operator. Now `sizeof` a pointer variable is `4` bytes on yoru system. That's what you saw.

---

Long story short **Arrays are not pointers**. They are **different**. The second case might give you a wrong impression of that they are or even if your teacher said but it's not the case. Array decays into a pointer that doesn't make array a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Pointers and arrays are closely related, but they are not equivalent.

In most contexts, the name of an array will *decay* to a pointer to the first element.  There are a few instances however where this does not happen, specifically when the array is the operand of the `sizeof` operator (yes, it is an operator, not a function).

So in the expression `sizeof(v)`, the name `v` does not decay because it is the operand of the `sizeeof` operator.  As a result, size of the entire array is given.  In contrast, `sizeof(v+0)` is different because `v` is an operand of the `+` operator.  In this case, `v` does in fact decay to a pointer and pointer arithmetic is performed.  This gives an expression of type `int *` which is then the operand to `sizeof`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll have to look more into decaying, as it hasn't been mentioned in my lectures. I would also like to apologize for the bad formatting and thank you for correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

> I would expect that sizeof(v) also returned 4

*No*.

To start with, `v` is not a pointer, it's an array. Arrays *decay* to pointers. Read more in [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

When you call `sizeof(v)`, you will get the size of your array in bytes.

20 is equal to 4 * 5 = 4 * N, where N is the number of elements in your array.

Moreover notice, that in your system an int is of size 4 bytes.

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to look over that question regarding array decaying.